# Remote Desktop from a ubuntu 13.04 to an Ubuntu 13.04 machine so the user on the second machine can see my movments

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, remote-access

I would like to remote desktop/VPN from an Ubuntu 13.04 computer (a) to an Ubuntu 13.04 computer(b) so the user(s) on the second machine can see my movements.

I would like something a lot like team-viewer or Join.me but these machines do not have Internet but that are attached on a local network and I can VPN to them but that can not see what I am doing and I need them to be able to see my movements.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes standard with 'Remote Desktop'. This is an application to do exactly this.
This uses vnc so you can use any vnc client you want, even on your smarth phone. Just search for vnc in the software center.

In the terminal you can issue:

`vncviewer -fullscreen 192.168.2.23:0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Epoptes.

Epoptes is an open source computer lab management and monitoring tool. It allows for screen broadcasting and monitoring, remote command execution, message sending, imposing restrictions like screen locking or sound muting the clients and much more!

To show your screen to others you can broadcast your screen as shown below

[image]

To install epoptes

`sudo  apt-get install epoptes`

configurations goes [here](http://www.epoptes.org/installation)

Answer (score 0):

By default Ubuntu have packages installed for remote desktop client named
"Remmina desktop client"
search in Ubuntu Dash for Remmina and you will get it.
But Remmina is useful inside your LAN network and for general purpose you can use "Teamviewer"
an excellent tool for remote desktop sharing purpose.It is in Ubuntu repository.